# Unable to build pyopenjtalk: CMake or C compiler issue?

Tags: python, cmake

I tried to build pyopenjtalk but got the error. Not sure where the problem is. I have installed Visual Studio 2022 and added below paths

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx86\x86
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin
```

to my Windows 11 system PATH.

The output is below:

```
C:\AI_Apps\pyopenjtalk-0.3.3> pip install -e .

Obtaining file:///C:/AI_Apps/pyopenjtalk-0.3.3
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [75 lines of output]
      setup.py:26: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        _CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33522.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33522.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
      CMake Error at C:/Users/micro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-zbehn4lj/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
        The C compiler

          "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

        is not able to compile a simple test program.

        It fails with the following output:

          Change Dir: 'C:/AI_Apps/pyopenjtalk-0.3.3/lib/open_jtalk/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-n7w7zc'

          Run Build Command(s): C:/Users/micro/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-zbehn4lj/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_df566\fast
                  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\build
          Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_df566.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
                  C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj.d --working-dir=C:\AI_Apps\pyopenjtalk-0.3.3\lib\open_jtalk\src\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-n7w7zc --filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe @C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\nm15E4.tmp
          testCCompiler.c
          Linking C executable cmTC_df566.exe
                  C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1623.tmp
          Visual Studio Incremental Link with embedded manifests
          Create CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/manifest.rc
          Create empty: CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/embed.manifest
          RC Pass 1:
          rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/manifest.rc
          RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
          The system cannot find the file specifiedNMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1623.tmp' : return code '0xffffffff'
          Stop.
          NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_df566.dir\build' : return code '0x2'
          Stop.





        CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      CMake is in the system path. Version:               cmake version 3.28.3

      CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zbehn4lj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 191, in <module>
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 457, in check_returncode
          raise CalledProcessError(self.returncode, self.args, self.stdout,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '..', '-DHTS_ENGINE_INCLUDE_DIR=.', '-DHTS_ENGINE_LIB=dummy']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: "CMake or C compiler issue?" - The issue with absence of `rc` utility in the PATH. See the duplicate question about ways for fix that.